# check 2 consecutive occurrences of the same letter

Tags: python, regex

Is there a method in python that helps me find 2 consecutive characters in a string?

Perhaps regex might be of use as well?

For example:

`a = "apple"`

`consecCheck(a) --> returns True` because there are 2 consecutive p's in the string

`b = "candyman"`

`consecCheck(b) --> returns False` because no consecutive characters have been found

The only method I can think of is a loop through the string to see if it's next character is the same as the previous.

Comment: I think you solved this one already.  Regex probably isn't a good choice, and there's not going to be anything that could do it faster than a linear search

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> def consecCheck(s):
...     return any(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s, s[1:]))
...
>>> consecCheck("apple")
True
>>> consecCheck("candyman")
False
```

What does the `zip` do here (make a pairs of characters):

```
>>> s = 'apple'
>>> zip(s, s[1:])
[('a', 'p'), ('p', 'p'), ('p', 'l'), ('l', 'e')]
```

---

Using regular expression (backreference):

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> def consecCheck(s):
...     return bool(re.search(r'(.)\1', s))
...
>>> consecCheck("apple")
True
>>> consecCheck("candyman")
False
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add the case where 'ee' and 'oo' specifically in the string woudl return True. As in they were the only exceptions

Comment: @Liondancer, Do you mean `False` ? Try `any(c1 == c2 and (c1 not in ('e', 'o')) for c1, c2 in zip(s, s[1:]))`

Comment: @Liondancer, Do you mean `consecCheck('cool')` should return `True`, while `consecCheck('baam')` return `False` ?

Comment: Just check `'oo' in word or 'ee' in word`.

Comment: well I wanted to create a case where say "aaoo" is false because it has "aa" but "ooer" returns True

Comment: +1 for multiple concise solutions in single answer. :)

Comment: @Liondancer, `consecCheck('apple')` should return `True`, right?

Comment: sorry i mean aa --> true and ooer --> false

Comment: @Liondancer, What about `aaoo`?

Comment: That should return True.

Comment: @Liondancer Try this for the regular expression solution:  (?!oo|ee)(.)\1